# Get tikz domain and range

Tags: tikz-pgf, domain

How can one get the tikz key values /tikz/domain (2 values) and /tikz/range (2 values)? In the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[domain=0:3,range=1:4] plot function{x**2} -- (0,3) -- (1,4);
\end{document}
```

I would like the numbers from `(0,3) -- (1,4)` read from the stored key values domain=0:3 and range=1:4. I tried to find a solution with `\pgfkeysvalueof` but I could not get it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said by @Heiko Oberdiek the settings are stored in the internal commands `\tikz@plot@domain` and `\tikz@plot@range`. So you can write some macros to extract them. Here is an example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
% extract interval `start:end` values
\def\get@interval@start#1:#2\@nil{#1}
\def\get@interval@end#1:#2\@nil{#2}
% get domain
\def\domainstart{\expandafter\get@interval@start\tikz@plot@domain\@nil}
\def\domainend{\expandafter\get@interval@end\tikz@plot@domain\@nil}
% get range
\def\rangestart{\expandafter\get@interval@start\tikz@plot@range\@nil}
\def\rangeend{\expandafter\get@interval@end\tikz@plot@range\@nil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[domain=0:3,range=1:4] plot  (\x,\x*\x) -- (\domainstart,\domainend) -- (\rangestart,\rangeend);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** I'm not a texpert, so probably a better macros can be used.

Comment: The parameter `#2` needs a limitation, otherwise, it only gets the first token token. Fix: `\def\get@domainstart#1:#2\@nil{#1}` and `\def\domainstart{\expandafter\get@domainstart\tikz@plot@domain\@nil}`. The same principle for the "range" and "end" cases.

Answer (score 7):

The settings are stored in the internal commands `\tikz@plot@domain` and `\tikz@plot@range`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikz\draw[domain=0:3,range=1:4] plot function{x**2} -- (0,3) -- (1,4)
  \pgfextra{%
    \typeout{Domain: \tikz@plot@domain}%
    \typeout{Range: \tikz@plot@range}%
  }
;
\end{document}
```

The console/`.log` file contains:

```
Domain: 0:3
Range: 1:4
```

I suggest using a different approach by defining macros to hold the values:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\MyDomainMin{0}
\def\MyDomainMax{3}
\def\MyRangeMin{1}
\def\MyRangeMax{4}
\tikz\draw[
  domain=\MyDomainMin:\MyDomainMax,
  range=\MyRangeMin:\MyRangeMax,
]
  plot function{x**2}
  -- (\MyDomainMin,\MyDomainMax) -- (\MyRangeMin, \MyRangeMax)
;
\end{document}
```

An example that makes a little more sense:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\MyDomainMin{0}
  \def\MyDomainMax{2.5}
  \def\MyRangeMin{1}
  \def\MyRangeMax{4}

  \draw[
    domain=\MyDomainMin:\MyDomainMax,
    range=\MyRangeMin:\MyRangeMax,
  ]
    plot[smooth] (\x, \x*\x)
  ;

  \draw[red]
    (\MyDomainMin, \MyRangeMin) rectangle (\MyDomainMax, \MyRangeMax)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]